# Method Assetic\AssetWriter::getCombinations() does not exist exception on symfony2 deploy using capifony

Tags: symfony, deployment, assetic, capifony

My deployment fail when calling:

```
cd /var/www/prod/releases/20130513164742 && php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

My setup worked fine yestertay but today I can't deploy it using the `cap deploy` command
I checked by cloning the repo in my prod environment and executing `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` (in dev mode), and it worked fine !

Any idea ?

```
 ** [out :: prod] executing "sh -c 'cd /var/www/prod/releases/20130513164742 && php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug'"
 ** [out :: prod] PHP Deprecated:  getEntityManager is deprecated since Symfony 2.1. Use getManager instead in /var/www/prod/shared/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Registry.php on line 71
 ** [out :: prod] Dumping all prod assets.
 ** [out :: prod] Debug mode is off.
 ** [out :: prod] 
 ** [out :: prod] 
 ** [out :: prod] 
 ** [out :: prod]                                                                 
 ** [out :: prod]   [ReflectionException]                                         
 ** [out :: prod]   Method Assetic\AssetWriter::getCombinations() does not exist  
 ** [out :: prod]                                                                 
 ** [out :: prod] 
 ** [out :: prod] 
 ** [out :: prod] assetic:dump [--watch] [--force] [--period="..."] [write_to]
 ** [out :: prod] 
 ** [out :: prod]
```

### Edit:

after updating vendor on my git clone I get this error

```
www-data@Prod:~/prod/dev$ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ManagerConfigurator::__construct() must be an array, none given, called in /var/www/prod/dev/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 116 and defined in /var/www/prod/dev/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/ManagerConfigurator.php on line 35
```

Comment: im getting the same issue. Did you update with composer today?

Comment: `kriswallsmith/assetic` got updated from alpha4 to beta1, https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/412

Comment: Yes ! since that it's broken ! Even in dev environment ! see my edit.

Comment: @Ascherer How can see whitch version I'm using in dev environment and How can I tell my composer stick to this version ?

Comment: check composer.lock, search for assetic, should see the version. check my answer for telling it what version to stick to

Answer (score 19, accepted):

https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/412

Add `"kriswallsmith/assetic": "v1.1.0-alpha4"`,

to your composer.json file, and update again

You'll want to change this when they fix the issue

***EDIT:***

For the record, moving to `"symfony/symfony": "2.3.*"` works now, without specifying the above

Comment: Dude I'm so **thankful** ! I was going crazy since 1 hour ! :D

Answer (score 5):

If someone still have probelm after add:

> `kriswallsmith/assetic": "v1.1.0-alpha4`

probably you need to change version for `symfony/assetic-bundle` to `2.3.*` (i have `2.1`)
and update again:

> php composer.phar update

Comment: With that Composer tells me that ascetic-bundle v2.3.0 requires kriswallsmith >= 1.1-beta1 which clashes with the requirement for 1.1.0-alpha4

Comment: Same here, but once changed to 1.1.0-beta1 everything updated fine.